# What is the proper command to restart a Dokku app from SSH?

Tags: docker, digital-ocean, dokku

A Rails app I deployed on DigitalOcean using Dokku crashed and started returning 500 errors.

How can I restart it without pushing an empty commit?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

`dokku ps:restart <app>` works for me logged in with `dokku` system user.

Use `dokku apps:list` to list your apps.

Comment: This worked for me, and seems official, as of 2016-12-22. I found my domain returning 502's (Bad Gateway) because my app was down.

Answer (score 31):

If you just want restart the web app, run `dokku deploy myapp`

Answer (score 23):

Found it [there](https://github.com/progrium/dokku/issues/182#issuecomment-23477252)! You have to use Docker `restart` command directly.

Connect to your server by SSH and run:

`` docker restart `cat /home/dokku/myapp/CONTAINER` ``

*myapp* being the name of my application. Change the path to your app if needed.

Comment: Atleast from v. 0.3.15 onwards you can run `dokku help` to see all available dokku commands.

Comment: `dokku ps:restart APP` would be the proper way to do this now.

Comment: I found this to cause trouble with dokku. It doesn't expect you to have gone behind its back and restart directly with docker.

Comment: thanks @Adamantish there is now an way to do it in dokku directly, I changed the accepted answer

Answer (score 12):

The proper way to restart an app is:

```
dokku release myapp
dokku deploy myapp
```

This is how it's done in [plugins/config/commands](https://github.com/progrium/dokku/blob/v0.2.3/plugins/config/commands#L51-L60) after setting environment variables:

```
config_restart_app() {
  APP="$1";

  echo "-----> Releasing $APP ..."
  dokku release $APP
  echo "-----> Release complete!"
  echo "-----> Deploying $APP ..."
  dokku deploy $APP
  echo "-----> Deploy complete!"
}
```

I have sent a [pull request](https://github.com/progrium/dokku/pull/653) to add a `dokku restart myapp` command.

Answer (score 5):

EDIT

The 'new' way appears to be to issue the command 'dokku ps:restart myapp'

END EDIT

An easier way might be to use a plugin:

https://github.com/scottatron/dokku-rebuild

Then issue

`dokku rebuild myapp`